# What are service bus and access control?

Tags: azure, access-control, servicebus

I am having a hard time understanding Windows Azure service bus and access control concepts. In layman's terms, what are they? What are they used for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Service Bus component of Windows Azure is meant to handle the problems arising from services that are living in multiple networks. Basically, a service bus just makes it appear as if your code is running on a single machine, while in reality it could be running anywhere within the Azure datacenters.
Access Control  lets you use "federated authentication for your service based on a claim-based RESTful model. (Sorry, copy&Paste from an O'Reilly book about Azure!)
Basically, when you create an Azure site, application or service, it could be running on any of the thousands of systems within the datacenter. And each of those systems has it's own IP address, it's own network, memory, processor and whatever more. To let them collaborate and to appear as a single system, these two services have been created. 
If you want to learn more about Azure, this would be a good moment to [buy a book](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596801984)! :-)
Azure is quite complex and service buses and access control are a bit more advanced topics.

Comment: Humm... I've read that book, and it's nice to get an overall idea about Azure, but just that.

Answer (score 0):

Service Bus is a solution for the integration between multiple applications whether they are hosted on the same infrastructure or even spread along multiple infrastructure or/and Cloud Computing provider.  If you search more in the internet you might find a lot about EAI (Enterprise application integration) here is my blog post about this topic:

http://hhaggan.wordpress.com/2013/03/07/introduction-to-enterprise-application-integration-eai/

and here another that I hope that helps you understand better what is the service bus:

http://hhaggan.wordpress.com/2013/03/09/introducing-service-bus/

in another words, it is a messaging platform that helps you communicate with multiple applications, softwares or services no matter what programming language they are written with or on which os or platform they are hosted on.  you will feel its effect specially when you work on connecting multiple nodes together, I don't mean 5 or 6 nodes but 10 and above.

Certainly there are several types of service bus, whether they are based on relayed messaging service or brokered messaging service, each one of them has several uses, its purpose and way of working.

For the Access control, this is so easy, it is a way of authentication and authorization for your application using third parties, It is a claim based identity that you can do the required authentication through the third party database.  you wont need to build everything from scratch in your database.  this helps a lot during development and I believe that this can help a lot in social media marketing and branding because of the use of facebook, twitter during the authentication.